# Why return is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this function returning “undefined”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143580/why-is-this-function-returning-undefined)

Why in following code return is `undefined` in case return should is `true`? what do i do?

```
<input type="text" value="" class="ticket_code">

function ticket_check() {
    var val = 'ticket_code=' + $('.ticket_code').val();
    var input_val = $('.ticket_code').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'get_ticket_code',
        data: val,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var result = true;
            if (data != 0) {
                $('div').empty().hide().fadeIn('slow').append(data + '<input name="name_ticket_code" value="' + data + '" style="display: none;">');
            } else {
                if (input_val) {
                    $('div').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                        $(this).empty();
                    })
                    result = false;
                }
            }
            return result
        }
    });
}

alert(ticket_check());
```

Comment: Because your `ticket_check()` function isn't returning anything.

Comment: `get_ticket_code` should be a url/file...

Comment: It's because you're returning from the `success` callback, not from `ticket_check()`.

Comment: The `success` (and `error`...) handler needs to do what you want to do when the `ticket_check()` returns.

Answer (score 2):

Because You are making an asynchronous call and so when the alert is executed nothing has been returned yet.

You could set async to false

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'get_ticket_code',
        data: val,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var result = true;
            if (data != 0) {
                $('div').empty().hide().fadeIn('slow').append(data + '<input name="name_ticket_code" value="' + data + '" style="display: none;">');
            } else {
                if (input_val) {
                    $('div').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                        $(this).empty();
                    })
                    result = false;
                }
            }
            return result
        }
    });
```

but this would lock the browser.

A better approach is to continue the flow from the "success" function according to the esit of the ajax call

Comment: I put `async: false,` in the code, but still is same `undefined` in output.

Comment: The main function still wouldn't return anything; it stays the callback that is returning.

Answer (score 2):

$.ajax call is asynchronous, you can't call and get a return value from it. The code return result doesn't get executed when you first call ticket_check.

Your function is already manipulating the DOM, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I put `async: false,` in the code, but still is same `undefined` in output.

Comment: @AliciaCibrian don't do that. just do your actions within success and error handler as Jared Farrish said. Event programming is a bit of paradigm change, is not like calling a function and getting a result. You ask for an action, you book for it, you have immediately the control back to do something else if needed, several milliseconds later, your ajax will come back and fire an event.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a common way to achieve what you're after: create some sort of "promise" object, which will be returned by `ticket_check()`:

```
function Promise() {
    var callback = function() {};

    this.onResult = function(result) {
        callback(result);
    }

    this.complete = function(handler) {
        callback = handler;
        return this;
    }
}

function ticket_check() {
    var promise = new Promise();

    // ...
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function (data) {
            var result = true;
            // ...
            promise.onResult(result);
        }
    });

    return promise;
}
```

This allows you to call code like this:

```
ticket_check()
    .complete(window.alert);
```

Comment: Nice. jQuery does have a [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) built-in (not sure what version it was introduced).

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading it, buy you named it `complete` but used `success`.

Comment: @Jared: Ha, that's pretty funny. I just honestly didn't know (my best guess is that we hand-rolled our own on my current project before it was introduced and have just been using that ever since). Yet another case of [jQuery doing absolutely everything!](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/does-jquery-turn-programmers-into-babies/) ;)

Comment: @pimvdb: No, you didn't miss anything... I just typed too fast. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning `true` (or `false`) in `$.ajax.success` event, which is running in a difference thread (not really a tread, but like it) asynchronously. And when you end the main method (as main thread), there is nothing to return. by setting `async:false` attr in ajax call, you can resolve the problem. The better way is to create a delegate for handling the result.

Comment: I put `async: false,` in the code, but still is same `undefined` in output.